How to Set Up an Approval Rule Based on the Last Segment's Seat Count in Salesforce CPQ?
I need to create an approval rule for a specific product related to dimension in Salesforce CPQ that triggers an approval process if the last segment in a Multi-Deal Quote (MDQ) configuration has a total seat count below 50. The last segment is identified using the Segment Index and the Segmented Quantity fields. For example, if the seat count in the final segment is under 50, the rule should trigger approval. However, if the total number of seats in the final segment exceeds 50, the rule should not trigger.
Could someone guide me through creating this rule or provide an example of formula syntax for identifying the last segment and checking its seat count?
I'm thinking we need to create through a price rule along with an approval
